# R raster function does not read rasters like it did before?

Tags: r, r-raster

I am currently working through my R scripts and it seems the old raster() function from the raster package doesn't work anymore. I get the following error when I do raster("filename")
Error in extension(x) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
Did something change with the new version of raster package? Or maybe the extension function might have changed and the raster function is still using the same way it did before the update?
Thanks for your help
Robby

Comment: Samething when you use the example:
logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
Error in extension(x) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems there was a version issue between R and the packages. All you need to do is update everything to the newest version.